# How can I set tex filetypes to use plaintex solarized coloring

Tags: terminal, filetype-tex

I use solarized for my terminal color. When I first create a new tex file and begin writing, I get the plaintex colorscheme, which I like. But once I save and reopen, I get the tex colorscheme, which seems lacking. I can use "set filetype=tex" to get the color back, but I cannot get it to run from the tex.vim file. I'm sure there's a better way to get the coloring I want.

Comment: You prefer the `plaintex` colorscheme? That's odd. Anyway, I think you are interested in the option `g:tex_flavor` (see `:h g:tex_flavor`). I.e., you will probably want to add `let g:tex_flavor = 'plain'` to your vimrc file.